# Homomorphism and Orthogonal idempotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following mapping a homomorphism of rings:

$ \varphi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z \ x \ Z} $

$ \varphi(a) = (a, a) $

$ \ $I know hom's preserve orthogonal idempotents, so in this case I guess $\{0,1\} \to \{\:(0,0), (1,1)\:\}\ $ which are still orthogonal idempotent

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, sure $\phi$ is a homomorphism, assuming component-wise operations in $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$:

$\phi(a + b) = (a + b, a + b) = (a, a) + (b, b), \tag{1}$

and

$\phi(ab) = (ab, ab) = (a, a) \cdot (b, b). \tag{2}$

The idempotents $e \in \Bbb Z$, satisfying as they must $e^2 = e$, are limited to integers such that $e(e - 1) = 0$, and since $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain, we must have $e = 0$ or $e = 1$; for such $e$,

$\phi(e) = (e, e) \tag{3}$

and we therefore have

$(\phi(e))^2 = (e, e)^2 = (e, e) \cdot (e, e) = (e^2, e^2) = (e, e) = \phi(e) = (0, 0) \; \text{or} \; (1, 1),  \tag{4}$

showing both that $\phi(e)$ is idempotent and that it must be $(0, 0)$ or $(1, 1)$.

It is thus correct to say that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, and that it maps the idempotents $0, 1$ to the idempotents $(0, 0), (1, 1)$, respectively.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Your map is a ring homomorphism, just check the definition. But your discussion on idempotents does not make any sense. It does not guarantee that the map is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Just make sure you understand the definition.